# Solving delay differential equation. DSolve returns `Indeterminate`

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, nonlinear, boundary-conditions

I want to solve the following systems of delay differential equations

$$
\text{SYSTEM 1}\\
x'(t) = -y'(t)-z'(t)\\
y'(t) = -z'(t) + x(t)y(t) \tanh(t)\\
z'(t) = -\Theta(t-2)x'(t-2)
$$

and
$$
\text{SYSTEM 2}\\
x'(t) = -y'(t)-z'(t)\\
y'(t) = -z'(t) + x(t)y(t) \tanh(t-3)\\
z'(t) = -\Theta(t-2)x'(t-2)
$$

with $x(0)=100$ , $z(0)=0$ and $y(0)=0.1$.

I am using the following code

```
sys1 = DSolve[{x'[t] == -y'[t] - z'[t], y'[t] == -z'[t] + x[t] y[t] Tanh[t], z'[t] == -Boole[t - 2 > 0] x'[t - 2], x[t /; t < 0] == 100, z[t /; t < 0] == 0, y[t /; t < 0] == 0.1}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 30}]

sys2 = DSolve[{x'[t] == -y'[t] - z'[t], y'[t] == -z'[t] + x[t] y[t] Tanh[t], z'[t] == -Boole[t - 2 > 0] x'[t - 2], x[t /; t < 0] == 100, z[t /; t < 0] == 0, y[t /; t < 0] == 0.1}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 30}]
```

The output that I get is shown in the following picture.

I have several questions

1. Is Mathematica returning a numerical solution? The appearance of those digits is suspicious...
2. Why very small imaginary numbers are appearing?
3. Why Mathematica is returning `Indeterminate` for `t>2`? Does it mean that Mathematica is not able to get the right solution?
4. Why the system 2 is completely undetermined?

**Output of system 1**
 [image]
**Output of system 2**
 [image]

Comment: Try `NDSolve` instead.

Comment: @Alx I would like an analytic solution ( if possible) and the answer to the 4 questions I asked. I already solved the system numerically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much progress can be made symbolically.  First, however, it is useful to solve the systems numerically to have some understanding of the behavior of the solutions, which is straightforward.  For system 1,

```
sys1n = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -y'[t] - z'[t], y'[t] == -z'[t] + x[t] y[t] Tanh[t], 
    z'[t] == -Boole[t - 2 > 0] x'[t - 2], x[t /; t < 0] == 100, 
    z[t /; t < 0] == 0, y[t /; t < 0] == 1/10}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[Evaluate@Through[sys1n[t]], {t, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {t, "x,y,z"}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

We see that `x` begins at about `100` but abruptly drops to very nearly (but not exactly) zero at `t` of order `1/3`.  At the same time, `y` rises to about `100`, but drops to approximately zero at `t` of order `7/3`,  replaced by `z` rising to about `100`.  This behavior can be explained easily by integrating the first and third equations symbolically.  The first obviously yields

```
x[t] + y[t] + z[t] == 1001/10
```

where the right side of the integrated equation is just the sum of initial conditions for the three variables.  The third yields

```
z{t] == 0
```

for `t < 2` and

```
z[t] = 100 - x[t - 2]
```

for larger `t`.  Hence, whatever `100 - x[t]` does, `z[t]` does at `t + 2`, which clearly is the case in the plot.  And, the integral of the first equation, above, gives `y[t]`.  The behavior of `x[t]` and `y[t]` for `t < 2` can be obtained symbolically from

```
sys1 = DSolveValue[{x'[t] == -y'[t] - z'[t], y'[t] == -z'[t] + x[t] y[t] Tanh[t], 
    z'[t] == 0, x[0] == 100, z[0] == 0, y[0] == 1/10}, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, t]

(* {100100/(1000 + Cosh[t]^(1001/10)), 
    (1001 Cosh[t]^(1001/10))/(10 (1000 + Cosh[t]^(1001/10))), 0} *)
```

a plot of which reproduces the curves above for `t < 2`.  We have, therefore, to high accuracy a complete symbolic solution for the first system.  To answer the first three questions posed by the OP.

1. Mathematica is returning a symbolic solution but with numbers in decimal form, because `y[0]` was specified in decimal form in the Question.  Curiously, specifying `y[0]` in rational form causes `DSolve` to run seemingly forever (at least in Version 12)!
2. `DSolve` as written in the Question first solves system 1 without boundary conditions and then applies the boundary conditions to evaluate the resulting constants of integration.  Experimentation shows that the process involves complex numbers that almost cancel to yield numbers that are real up to roundoff.  Hence, the tiny imaginary numbers in the solution shown in the Question.
3. Indeed, Mathematica returns `Indeterminate` for `t > 2`, because it cannot solve the equations in this region.  This is an undocumented "feature", I believe.

Solving system 2 symbolically may not be possible, but progress can be made.  As before, first solve it numerically.

```
sys2n = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -y'[t] - z'[t], y'[t] == -z'[t] + x[t] y[t] Tanh[t - 3], 
    z'[t] == -Boole[t - 2 > 0] x'[t - 2], x[t /; t < 0] == 100, 
    z[t /; t < 0] == 0, y[t /; t < 0] == 1/10}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 10},
    WorkingPrecision -> 90, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];
Plot[Evaluate@Through[sys2n[t]], {t, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {t, "x,y,z"}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

With the approximation that `z[t] == 0` until `x[t]` decreases noticeably, system 2 yields

```
sys2nobc = (DSolve[{x'[t] == -y'[t] - z'[t], y'[t] == -z'[t] + x[t] y[t] Tanh[t - 3], 
    z'[t] == 0, z[0] == 0}, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, t] // Flatten) 
    /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2} /. Exp[c1 c2] -> c3
(* {y[t] -> -((c1 c3)/(-c3 + (1 - Tanh[3 - t]^2)^(c1/2))), 
    x[t] -> (c1 (1 - Tanh[3 - t]^2)^(c1/2))/(-c3 + (1 - Tanh[3 - t]^2)^(c1/2)), 
    z[t] -> 0} *)
Solve[Evaluate[{x[t] - 100 == 0, y[t] - 1/10 == 0} /. sys2nobc /. t -> 0], 
    {c1, c3}, WorkingPrecision -> 120] // Flatten
(* {c1 -> 100.10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 
    c3 -> -4.0443105223898349654407241717842692089189077992*10^-104} *)
```

Plotting the result reproduces the `t < 2` segment of the second figure above but reproduces the first abrupt change in the second figure above only qualitatively.  It seems unlikely that `DSolve` can do better, even with additional human assistance.  To address the OP's fourth question,

4. `DSolve` can solve system 2 for `t < 2` only with human assistance as just given.  Left on its own, it cannot solve system 2 for any `t`.

Comment: Thank you very much!